# awk for loop error when using if else

Tags: awk

Here is the datafile t2, separated by tab

```
_Ibaseebna1_1 0.79(0.28-2.22) 0.6540
_Ibaseebna1_2 0.88(0.48-1.62) 0.6900
_Ibaseebna1_3 0.78(0.32-1.86) 0.5700
ptrend 0.93(0.72-1.20) 0.5800
_Ibaseebna1_1 1.85(0.60-5.73) 0.2850
_Ibaseebna1_2 1.89(0.57-6.27) 0.2950
_Ibaseebna1_3 3.21(1.00-10.33) 0.0510
ptrend 1.39(1.05-1.85) 0.0200
pinteraction 1.39(0.93-2.10) 0.1120
```

i want to remove the value of second column if the $1==ptrend or ==pinteraction.

The results should be like:

```
_Ibaseebna1_1 0.79(0.28-2.22) 0.6540
_Ibaseebna1_2 0.88(0.48-1.62) 0.6900
_Ibaseebna1_3 0.78(0.32-1.86) 0.5700
ptrend     0.5800
_Ibaseebna1_1 1.85(0.60-5.73) 0.2850
_Ibaseebna1_2 1.89(0.57-6.27) 0.2950
_Ibaseebna1_3 3.21(1.00-10.33) 0.0510
ptrend     0.0200
pinteraction     0.1120
```

I can do this use the code :

```
awk -F' ' ' {
               if ( $1=="ptrend" ) print $1," "," ",$3;
               else
               if ( $1=="pinteraction" ) print $1," "," ",$3;
               else
               print $0; }' t2.txt > t3.txt
```

But when i try to use the for loop:

```
for i in ptrend pinteraction
do

awk -F' ' -v p=$i '{
                if ( $1==p ) print $1," "," ",$3;
                else
                print $0; }' t2.txt > t3.txt
done
```

which give the results like :

```
_Ibaseebna1_1 0.79(0.28-2.22) 0.6540
_Ibaseebna1_2 0.88(0.48-1.62) 0.6900
_Ibaseebna1_3 0.78(0.32-1.86) 0.5700
ptrend 0.93(0.72-1.20) 0.5800
_Ibaseebna1_1 1.85(0.60-5.73) 0.2850
_Ibaseebna1_2 1.89(0.57-6.27) 0.2950
_Ibaseebna1_3 3.21(1.00-10.33) 0.0510
ptrend 1.39(1.05-1.85) 0.0200
pinteraction     0.1120
```

Anything wrong with the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem with the loop is that it is a loop. Writing a shell loop just to manipulate text is always the wrong approach. You can do what you describe in one brief, trivial awk command with no surrounding shell loop:

```
awk '!/^_/{$2=""}1' t2
```

Answer (score 2):

You operate on the original file each time through the shell loop. So your output is the last run of awk not the combination of runs.

If you want to use this method of doing this (and I don't think you do) you would need to use a temporary file during each loop and then move that to the original file name at the end of each loop (or similar).

But the original awk script is better than the loop.

Even better though would be something like this though I think:

```
awk -F $'\t' '
    BEGIN {
        map["ptrend"]=1
        map["pinteraction"]=1
    }

    map[$2] {$2=""}
    {print}
' t2.txt > t3.txt
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but possibly more general than the OP needs.  The OP might be happy with a simple: `awk '$1~/ptrend|pinteraction/{$2=""}1' t2`

Comment: Or possibly even the much simpler: `awk '$1!~/^_/{$2=""}1' t2`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yeah, I considered doing the tests in the pattern directly but figured this might be a little more useful of a method to show off.